# Can't get current location using gps (App Crash)

Tags: android, gps

Everything ok when I run app on emulator, but when I run app on my phone (samsung galaxy mini) my app crash (I don't know why, I did turn on gps and internet).

Code:

```
public class atm_atmogan extends MapActivity {
    LocationManager mlocManager;
    LocationListener mlocListener;
    MapController mapController;
    MapView mapView;
    Location location;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.atm_atmogan);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapView.invalidate();
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(17);

        mlocManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = mlocManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mlocListener);
        mapController.animateTo(convertLoc(location));
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            location = loc;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS OFF",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
}
```

`convertLoc` is function I created to convert *Location* to *GeoPoint*.

Update Logcat when i run on real device:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at tim_atm.namespace.atm_atmogan.convertLoc(atm_atmogan.java:115) 
at tim_atm.namespace.atm_atmogan.onCreate(atm_atmogan.java:146) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
```

Update layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0rMwFsILEdg4813dweucAH5iRKJHGozQs8FFvzQ" 

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put your error in your question...

Comment: What is the LogCat output when the application crashes?

Comment: When i run app on emulator ... everything ok.. not error. App crash when i run app on my real phone (Samsung galaxy mini)..

Comment: Run the application on your device while it's still connected to your PC. When it crashes, copy and paste the LogCat output here.

Comment: I use linux and when i run app on my computer. I can't choose my phone :(. Can you tell my how to fix it. http://qhoang.org/up/files/nnochosd.png

Comment: i have update Logcat when i run on real device... help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check that `mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation()` is returning a non null value.

Comment: i don't know why method getLastKnownLocation() return null value... I testing on real device. Can you tell me how to solved my problem.

Comment: Enable your gps and go out in open so that the device can access the gps satellite and store a location also call the  'mapController.animateTo(convertLoc(location));' with some default value if the location is null and call the 'mapController.animateTo(convertLoc(location));' from onLocationChanged() method of the listener.

Comment: i had enable gps, internet,use wireless networks, use GPS satellites :(

Comment: May be device can not access the gps satellites from the office. Trying going out in open and see if it can access the gps satellites.

Comment: You can also use the following application to capture logs on real device  [Log Collector for android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector)

Answer (score 0):

GetLastKnownLocation dont guaranteed that you will get location. You should listen for location change then use that location as a back up plan. You may want to try getLastKnownLocation using other parameters.

Also, you may want to remove your Map API key ;)